# Invalid Username and password in magento hosted site

Tags: magento-1.8, theme, login

I installed a fresh magento community edition 1.8.

I installed using "themename_full package.rar" rar file, which includes basic

magento  themes[blank, default, modern, iphone] and also custom theme named as "themename".

In Phpmyadmin, I reset password in admin_user table with (MD5) function.

I am facing 2 problems.

1)i can not able to login to admin, with right username and password.

2)Frontend is working, but instead of custom theme "themename", default magento theme is displaying.

Please help me in giving solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any error for admin?

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply, yes, Invalid Username or password

Comment: This is not a "do my work for free" site. Here we try to assist people with Magento issues, both merchants and developers but we also work. Please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a small script](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2012/02/create-admin-user-by-code.html) that allows you to create an admin user.
The idea is to create a file, instantiate the application and just use the models to create an admin.
After logging in you can change the fronten theme as explained by programmer_rkt or you can take a look at [this tutorial.](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_themes.htm)

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for reply, I created adminuser.php in root[public_html].

can you please visit http://schoolboards2.newtrendzonline.com/ also

http://schoolboards2.newtrendzonline.com/adminuser.php

Is there anything else i have to do?

Comment: @user3483987. There is something wrong with one of your modules declaration file. In `app/etc/modules` there is some invalid xml

Comment: @user3483987. Sorry but I can't do that right now. I'm at work.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, my friend @tbi_infotech give you an answer. This is the answer for your second question

By default, Magento uses a theme  `default` package and `default` theme. In order to change this, you need to get into admin and specify your package and and your theme.

So these are the step that you need to do here

1. *Check which package holds your custom theme `themename`.*

Your `themename` resides in this location `app/design/frontend/<package_name>/themename`. I am not sure about which package that holds your theme. It may be `default` or some other packages. Basically name of  parent directory that holds your theme is the package name.

2. *specify package and theme in admin side.*

For this you need to go `system -> configuration.` There under `design` tab, you should set data somewhat like this. Here I assume the package that hold your theme is `packagename`

[image]

**Note: Don't forget to change the current scope to your store.**  It can modify at top left area of the page. If you set this to `default config` option, then this package/theme will apply for all website stores. If you have only one website | store, there is no issue.

That's it. clear all cache and then load the page.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

If you have command line access you could always try using [N98-Magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun). This has a number of useful tools for development process, including one for resting the admin password.

The command you are looking for is:

```
n98-magerun.phar admin:user:change-password [username] [password]
```

Answer (score 1):

Install a fresh magento, and go to

`admin_user` table

Use that password and paste it to your this magento install it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, okay, i will try this, why  frontend is not displaying with custom theme?

Comment: I am not sure check if you have done proper settings

Comment: OK, Hopefully you are now able to login

Comment: Hi, 

For sure, There is some wrong i am doing about username and passwords. 

because i installed magento again with another themepackage, but again

"Invalid User Name or Password."

Comment: Try this link:

http://www.phpgenious.com/2010/02/cant-login-into-admin-panel-of-magento-problem-and-solution/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, unfortunately it did't worked for me.